# Installing PHP7 on CentOS 6.8, encountering GLIBC issue

Tags: centos6, php7, glibc

I am trying to install PHP 7 from REMI repo, I managed to install it but when I try to issue command:

```
yum install php70
```

I get error

```
Error: Package: php70-php-cli-7.0.12-2.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-safe)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)(64bit)
```

I tried to look into installing GLIBC_2.15 on CentOS 6.8 but mostly found that it is not recommended. Is there any workaround or better way to install php7?

Comment: Dont mix and match packages and repos for el6 and el7.

Answer (score 4):

You are obviously trying to install a EL-7 package on an EL-6 distro.

- Remove the remi-release package
- install the correct version
- yum clean metadata

And PHP 7 is also available for EL-6 in my repo.

Reminder: follow the [Wizard](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/) instructions.